# ¿Cómo poner 3 elementos en un línea?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

¿Qué tengo que poner para que me aparezcan los 3 elementos en la misma linea y unidos?

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<div class="terms">
    <a class="term" href="#"> {{ 'TERM_SERVICE' | translate }}</a>
    <p class="space" > | </p>
    <a class="privacy" href="#">{{ 'PRIVACY_POLICY' | translate }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Has intentado algo? Cóloca algo de tu css para que podamos echarte un cable.Echale un vistazo a [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Para ponerlos en fila no necesitas css en este caso. Aunque obviamente lo tendras que poner para maquetarlo.

Lo que te pasa es que la etiqueta `<p>` viene con un salto de página "incluido" digamos. Si dejas el texto fuera, entre link y link, veras como te coloca todo seguido.

```html
<div class="terms">
    <a class="term" href="#"> {{ 'TERM_SERVICE' | translate }}</a>
    |
    <a class="privacy" href="#">{{ 'PRIVACY_POLICY' | translate }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: En vez de dejarlo solo el pipe, lo pondría dentro de un `<span>` que tiene los estilos en `display: inline`.

Comment: En CSS siempre puedes tratar de cambiar la propiedad [display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Si definitivamente quieres mantener tu código HTML y que aparezcan en la misma línea los 3 elementos, tendrás que usar Flexbox (o al menos es la opción más sencilla), definiendo el `<div>` como el contenedor:

```css
.terms {
  display: flex;
}

.terms > p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="terms">
    <a class="term" href="#"> {{ 'TERM_SERVICE' | translate }}</a>
    <p class="space" > | </p>
    <a class="privacy" href="#">{{ 'PRIVACY_POLICY' | translate }}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

si no quieres romperte mucho la cabeza, cambia la etiqueta `p` por `span`, es decir:

`<span class="space" > | </span>`

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente como te han dicho, el elemento

es un elemento de bloque, por lo tanto siempre empiezan en una linea nueva o con un salto, como lo prefieras ver, ademas de ocupar el 100% del espacio.

O bien sacas " | " de la etiqueta

como te han dicho, o si por el contrario necesitas tenerlo en un

pero en linea, hazle que sea un inline-block, y tambien solucionas el problema